# Is it possible to compile managed source with different compiler flags than unmanaged source?

Tags: scala, sbt

I've added the `-Xlinter` and `-Ywarn-unused-import` scalac flags to a project of mine. The problem is that I'm using a source generator and it creates code that doesn't pass all the checks - there are dead code and unused import warnings. Is there a way for me to have a different set of `scalacOptions` for managed vs. unmanaged code?

Comment: I've wondered about this too, and have always just fixed the warnings in the code gen. You might get a faster answer on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/sbt/sbt).

Comment: Unfortunately the code generator is Scalate. It'd probably be simpler to rip it out than to try and fix it. :-/ For now I'm going to work around the problem by moving things to different modules.

Comment: Using subprojects is the right way to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

I'll copy what Seth answered in comment section.

> Using subprojects is the right way to go about this.